# Synchronize multiple realtime inputs

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, alsa, v4l2

I'm trying to record a video+audio using `ffmpeg` from 3 sources: `x11grab` (desktop), `v4l2` (webcam) and `alsa` (microphone). I'm using this script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

set -x

out=$1
rm -vf $out
rate=25
cam_size="848x480"
x11_size="1920x1080"
tqs="-thread_queue_size 512"

ffmpeg \
    -f x11grab $tqs -video_size $x11_size -framerate $rate -i :0.0 \
    -f v4l2 $tqs -video_size $cam_size -input_format mjpeg -framerate $rate -i /dev/video0 \
    -f alsa $tqs -i hw:0,0  \
    -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=424:240 [ovrl],[0:v][ovrl]overlay=x=W-w-32:y=H-h-32" \
    -vcodec libx264 -r $rate -preset fast -b 4000k -s $x11_size \
    -acodec aac -ar 48000 -ab 128k \
    $out
```

but all sources are not syncronized: audio is going first, then webcam and then desktop (webcam with small delay ~1sec, desktop with bigger delay ~3sec).

What is wrong with this command? How to synchronize all realtime streams to be recorded without delay?

Comment: And you not only have the problem that they all *start* with a different delay; even if you adjust for the delay, all three sources will have slightly different clocks, so if you record for a longer time, they'll go out of sync again... (I don't have an answer to this question, but I'd like one, too).